# Mongo Map Dot notation

Tags: mongodb

I would like to construct a query that will return just the names of the classes for the datastructure below. 
So far, the closest I've come is using dot notation

```
db.mycoll.find({name:"game1"},{"classes.1.name":true})
```

But the problem with this approach is that it will only return the name of the first class. Please help me get the names of all three classes.

I wish I could use a wild card as below, but I'm not sure if that exists.

```
db.mycoll.find({name:"game1"},{"classes.$*.name":true})
```

Datastructure:

```
{
"name" : "game1",
"classes" : {
    "1" : {
        "name" : "warlock",
        "version" : "1.0"
    },
    "2" : {
        "name" : "shaman",
        "version" : "2.0"
    },
    "3" : {
        "name" : "mage",
        "version" : "1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered making `classes` an array instead of an embedded  doc with numerical properties?  That would be the traditional approach.

Comment: I have, but for our use case a map is desireable for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple query that will achieve the results you seek. MongoDB has limited support for querying against sub-objects or arrays of objects. The basic premise with MongoDB is that you are querying for the top-level document.

That said, things are changing and you still have some options:

1. Use the new [MongoDB Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/). This has a `$project` operation that should do what you're looking for.
2. You can return just the `classes` field and then merge the `names` together. This should be trivial with most languages.

Note, that it's not clear what you're doing with `classes`. Is this an array or an object? If it's an object, what does `classes.1` actually represent? Is it different from `classes.warlock`?

Comment: I'm attempting suggestion 2 at the moment. I was unaware of the Aggregation Framework. Thanks for the suggestion :)

It's an object. 1 is the id of the object, and name (and many other fields and sub-objects actually) is part of the object's metadata.

Comment: Mr. Gates VP, 
 Might I trouble you for a sample of how you were thinking of using the $project operator?

Comment: Well, if `classes` is an array, then you can `$unwind: '$classes'` and `$project: { 'name': 1 }`. However, the unwind does not work with objects. It looks like the `1` is an object, so the aggregation framework will probably not work here.